# What are the conditions on using Eisenstein reduction of ternary quadratic forms?

Tags: number-theory, quadratic-forms, sagemath

The ternary quadratic form $Q(x,y,z) = -3 x^2 + 3 x y + 3 x z - y^2 - y z - z^2$ is not positive definite. In *Sage*, using code found in this [link](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/quadratic_forms/sage/quadratic_forms/ternary_qf.html),

Q = TernaryQF([-3, -1, -1, -1, 3, 3])

Qr, m = Q.reduced_form_eisenstein()

Qr

Qr.is_eisenstein_reduced()

nothing is returned by *Sage*. Why is nothing returned by *Sage*, what are the conditions on using Eisenstein reduction, what is a reference on Eisenstein reduction of ternary quadratic forms, and if $Q(x, y, z)$ does not satisfy the conditions for Eisenstein reduction, is there another appropriate reduction that might be used in such a case?

Answer (score 2):

your form is negative semidefinite, a binary form in disguise. Note that the determinant of the Hessian matrix of second partials is zero.

In my standard order $$ x^2, y^2, z^2, yz, zx, xy  $$
you have ordered coefficients
$$ -3,-1,-1,-1,3,3 $$
This is $SL_3  \mathbb Z$ equivalent to
$$ -1,-1,-1,1,1,1 $$
or $$  -\frac{1}{2} \left( (v-w)^2 + (w-u)^2 + (u-v)^2 \right)  $$
by

$$ x=u, \; y = u+v-w , z=w   $$

This is also
$$ - \frac{1}{4} (2u - v - w )^2 - \frac{3}{4} ( v - w )^2 $$
of deficient rank